# Lectura de .json con React Hooks retorna array vacío

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

Estoy tratando de leer varios archivos locales .json y guardarlos en un Hook, el problema es que incluso después de asignar el valor correspondiente al hook, al mostrarlo me sale un array vacío.

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from 'react';


const Ingresar = () =>{

    const [Productos, setProductos] = useState([]);

    const traerJson = (nombre) =>{
        fetch("http://localhost/programacion/React/pcgamer/src/components/presupuesto/jsons/"+nombre+".json")
        .then(response =>{
            return response.json();
        } )
        .then(datos => setProductos(datos));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let arrayAux = ["almacenamiento", "fuentes", "gpu", "mothers", "procesadores", "ram"];
        for (let i = 0; i < 6 ; i++){
            traerJson(arrayAux[i]);
        }
        console.log(Productos)//Esto muestra un array vacío 
    }, [])


    return (
        /*Aquí hay código html*/
    );
}

export default Ingresar;
```

Probé mostrando la variable "datos" y al parecer tiene todos los datos que debería tener, no sé por qué no se actualiza el estado del hook.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez por que inicializas el estado como un arreglo, y después lo actualizas así

```
setProductos(datos)
```

Intenta con:

```
setProductos([...datos])
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, lo normal sería que tu Array de productos sólo tuviera como datos, el último GET, ya que el `setProductos` lo que hace es pisar lo que tuviera antes y poner el valor nuevo. Si lo que quieres es mantener los datos previos y concatenar los nuevos, lo que debes hacer es, como dice @Alfredows:

```
setProductos([...productos, datos]);
```

A parte, comprueba que esta parte:

```
.then(response =>{ return response.json(); }).then(datos => setProductos(datos));
```

Devuelve el valor que quieres y no un array vacío.

Comment: Probé con eso y mostrando el valor de datos y de productos, aunque use el setProductos de la forma que me recomendaste sigue sin tener el valor de datos ;( datos tiene todos los datos correctamente, pero no se los asigna a Productos

Answer (score 0):

Veo el código bien, deberías usar el spread como recomiendan los compañeros y también revisar que el ultimo archivo no este vació, podría ser el caso. Lo otro que me inquieta es que sea tal vez tema de asincronía, tal vez cuando se esta cargando el archivo tome algo de tiempo y el recorrido del ciclo se finalice primero que la carga del archivo, con lo cual al realizar la impresión ps te mostrara vació.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que no tienes ningún control de espera sobre la llamada AJAX. Al ser asíncrona no espera a que finalice y de ahí que el `console.log(Productos)` te aparezca vacío.

Prueba a usar el `async/await`, debería valirte.

También comprueba que la llamada a esa URL te devuelve datos, incluye un `console.log(datos)` dentro del `.then(datos => ...)`.